# What can I do when Visual Studio won't allow me to view a file of code, close the project, or close VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Whether I 2-click my *.cs file from Solution Explorer, select File > Close Solution, or select File > Exit,

I get the same wonky and macabre communique from the labyrinthine depths of the IDE:

[image]

Is it safe to Ctrl+Alt+Delete my way out of this trap, or is there another way to get bypass that obstruction?

BTW, I get the same thing if I try Build > Clean, Build > Rebuild, F5, etc. (seemingly *anything* from within the VS IDE).

However, I *am* able to look at other code files - it's only the one that dervies from ServiceBase that is recalcitrant.

Comment: Sounds like an extension issue. Have you tried that with running VS by switching to console and executing `devenv /safemode`? See this issue at Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1272620/when-i-install-the-visual-studio-installer-projects-extension-i-cant-open-code-editor

Comment: I was thinking maybe it had something to do with Windows Services, but that link is about a Winforms app, so I guess that's not it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to escape this Catch-22:

1. Open one of the other files in the project by 2-clicking it in the
   Solution Explorer.
2. Build the project (Ctrl+Shift+B)
3. Close the project
4. Reopen the project

You should then be able to open the formerly intransigent, if not transient, file.